# Restrict Who can change "Build Quality" in TFS

Tags: tfs, build-process, build-automation

When a build is in the completed section of the Build Explorer in Visual Studio the Build Quality can be assigned.

Is there a way to restrict who can set these?  Ideally I would love a way to restrict some to specific users (ie Prod Ready to the Testers) and others to another group (ie Test Ready to Developers)

Vaccano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that you cannot limit certain build qualities to groups of people in the current versions of TFS. There is just a single permission in TFS2008 of "Edit build quality" that will let you set the build to any of the defined qualities. By default this is assigned to the project administrators but you can assign it to an alternative group if you wish.  To do that right click on the Team Project in Team Explorer and go to Team Project Settings, Security...

Comment: Feature request?  For example, it'd be nice if only members of QA could say that a build is in a certain state.